# How to make voltage loops inside a circuit and move node label?

Tags: circuitikz, arc

I have this circuit below and want to draw voltage loops within the circuit so it is simiarly to the picture at the bottom. I have however seen someone use the arc, but it was not what i hoped for. Hope anyone can help me.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[american, straight voltages]
    \draw (-1,0)
    to [american voltage source, v=$V_P$, invert, voltage shift=1] (-1,4) %Input voltage  Vp
    to [R, R=$R_p$, i^>=$i_p$] (2,4)
    to [R=$R_L$] (4,4)
    to [L, l_=$L$, v^<=$v_L$, i=$i_L$, voltage shift=1.5] (7,4)
    
    to [Tnigbt,bodydiode] (10,4)
    to [short] (12,4)
    to [american voltage source, v^<=$V_{out}$, voltage shift=1] (12,0)
    to [short] (-1,0)
        
    (2.0,4) to [R=$R_Ci$, i=$i_{Ci}$] (2.0,1.5)
    to [C, l_=$C_i$, v^<=$v_{Ci}$] (2.0,0)
    
    (7.2,4) to [Tnigbt,bodydiode, invert] (7.2,0)
    
    (10.0,4) to [R=$R_Co$, i=$i_{Co}$] (10.0,1.5)
    to [C, l_=$C_o$, v^<=$v_{Co}$] (10.0,0)
    
    (8.5,5) node[align=center]{$G_2$}
    (6.1,2) node[align=center]{$G_1$}
    (7.2,0) node[circ, scale=1.5]{$1$}
    (7.2,4) node[circ, scale=1.5]
    (2,0) node[circ, scale=1.5]
    (2,4) node[circ, color=red, scale=1.5]
    (10,4) node[circ, color=red, scale=1.5]
    (10,0) node[circ, color=red, scale=1.5]
    
    ;
\end{circuitikz}    


\end{document}
```

This are the circuit i am trying to recreate

[image]

Comment: Is this what you want?
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/548319/274769

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304283/physical-model-of-transformer-using-circuitikz/304305?r=SearchResults&s=5%7C11.1501#304305

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I propose to define a macro that can put an "elliptical" arrow in the center of a mesh, feeding it three corners and the label. It can be tweaked a lot, but more or less, the idea could be the following one:

```latex
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx,RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\newcommand{\mesharrow}[5][red]{% optional: color, default red
    % mandatory: corner 1, corner 2, corner 3, label
    \coordinate (tmp-c) at ($(#2)!0.5!(#4)$);
    \node[#1] at (tmp-c) {#5};
    \draw[thick, -Stealth, #1]
    let \p1 = ($(#3)-(#2)$), \p2=($(#4)-(#3)$),
    \n1={0.3*veclen(\x1,\y1)}, \n2={0.3*veclen(\x2,\y2}
    in ($(tmp-c)+(0.3*\x1,0)$) arc(0:270:\n1 and \n2);
}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{% this definition is at tikz level, because
        % it will be used with a `node[... ]` element
        bigO/.style={circle, draw, fill=red, inner sep=2pt},
    }
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) coordinate(start)
        % this number here (5)--v is the one referenced below in text
        to [battery=$V_p$] ++(0,5) coordinate(corner1)
        to[R=$R_p$, f=$i_p$] ++(4,0) coordinate(corner2)
        to[R=$R_{ci}$, f=$i_{ci}$] ++(0,-2) coordinate(rci)
        to[C=$C_i$, v=$v_{ci}$, -*] (corner2|-start) coordinate(corner3)
        -- (start);
    %% rest of the circuit...
    \draw[dashed] (corner2) -- ++(1,0) (corner3) -- ++(1,0);
    %% red blobs
    \node [bigO] at (corner2) {};
    \node [bigO] at (rci) {};
    %%
    \mesharrow{corner1}{corner2}{corner3}{$i_1$}
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: mesh current]

Notice that the ellipse adjusts automatically to the mesh; if I change the number `5` marked above to `4` or `3` I have:

[image: mesh current with different shape]

Notice:

- The macro will use and reuse the coordinate named `tmp-c`. [Coordinates are global in Ti*k*Z](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459492/local-scoped-coordinate-names-in-tikz), so use a name that is not used anywhere else.
- You can use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123187/38080 to have more control over the arc position and angles.

Comment: Thanks, that is really helpful. Can you explain to me what (corner2|-start) does, becuase I dont think i quite understand the command.

Comment: It's one of the most useful Ti*k*Z  coordinate tricks for circuits; it means the point vertically from `corner2` and horizontally from `start`; see https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#pgf.perpendicular

Comment: Ah okay, it is a little confusing but think I get it. Can i reverse the direction of the arrow?

Comment: You mean, using `Stealth-` instead of `-Stealth`? Of course, look at arrows in the Ti*k*Z manual. I suggest going through the first Ti*k*Z tutorial, it'll save you a lot of time in the end! 

Comment: Ah okay thanks!