How to create rounded arrows to highlight inflection points in a TikZ graph?
I have drawn a graph with TikZ, including the corresponding inflection points. An inflection point marks the transition from a concave up curve to a concave down curve (or vice versa). I would like to illustrate this transition using rounded arrows. Here is my code:
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw [->] (-5,0) -- (6,0) node [right] {$x$};
     \draw [->] (0,-4) -- (0,5) node [above] {$y$};
     \node at (0,0) [below left] {$0$};
     \draw[scale=0.5, domain=-6.5:6.5, smooth, samples=300, variable=\x] plot ({\x}, {(2/437)*\x*\x*\x*\x*\x + (5/437)*\x*\x*\x*\x - (90/437)*\x*\x*\x - (280/437)*\x*\x + (800/437)*\x + 7});
     \filldraw[red] (-2,371/874) circle (1.5pt) node[text width=2cm,align=center, above] {};% {\textcolor{black}{lokaler Hochpunkt}};
     \filldraw[red] (-0.5,2072/874) circle (1.5pt) node[text width=2cm,align=center, above, yshift=3.5mm] {};
    \filldraw[red] (7/4,371/874) circle (1.5pt) node[text width=2cm,align=center, above] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

Here is the result of the above code:

And I would like to have arrows at the transitions like here:

The arrows should follow the same path as the graph up to and from the inflection point. I don't know how to create such rounded arrows.
Thank you in advance for your help.

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304283/physical-model-of-transformer-using-circuitikz/304305?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C24.3987#304305

@JohnKormylo The arrows should follow the same path as the graph up to and from the inflection point.

Should the arrows be parallel? So your last picture is actually not quite right since the arrows are just circular?

A bit of googling led me to this page which brought me to this idea:
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [->] (-5,0) -- (6,0) node [right] {$x$};
    \draw [->] (0,-4) -- (0,5) node [above] {$y$};
    \node at (0,0) [below left] {$0$};
    \draw[scale=0.5, domain=-6.5:6.5, smooth, samples=300, variable=\x] plot ({\x}, {(2/437)*\x*\x*\x*\x*\x + (5/437)*\x*\x*\x*\x - (90/437)*\x*\x*\x - (280/437)*\x*\x + (800/437)*\x + 7});
    \filldraw[red] (-2,371/874) circle (1.5pt) node[text width=2cm,align=center, above] {};% {\textcolor{black}{lokaler Hochpunkt}};
    \filldraw[red] (-0.5,2072/874) circle (1.5pt) node[text width=2cm,align=center, above, yshift=3.5mm] {};
    \draw[-stealth,line width=0.05cm,olive] ([shift=(160:1.3cm)]-0.5,2072/874) arc (180:-20:0.6cm);
    \node at ([shift=(160:1.25cm)]0.05,2072/874) {rechts};
    \filldraw[red] (7/4,371/874) circle (1.5pt) node[text width=2cm,align=center, above] {};
    \draw[-stealth,line width=0.05cm,orange] ([shift=(40:1.5cm)]7/4,371/874) arc (40:260:0.6cm);
    \node at ([shift=(40:0.9cm)]7/4,371/874) {links};
    
    % you can play around with parameters to suite your requirements 
    \draw[scale=0.4, domain=4.25:5.63, smooth, samples=400, variable=\x,red, line width=1pt,-stealth,xshift=1.2cm,yshift=0.5cm] plot ({\x}, {(2/437)*\x*\x*\x*\x*\x + (5/437)*\x*\x*\x*\x - (90/437)*\x*\x*\x - (280/437)*\x*\x + (800/437)*\x + 7});
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


Edit: added red arrow to represent a part of the path.

Thank you very much for your answer. It would be great if the arrows followed the same path as the graph up to and from the inflection point.

well, the command works like this:
\draw[...] ([shift=(t,r)] xpos , ypos ) arc ( start angle : end angle : radius );
where:
t: angle in which shift will occur
r: radius/distance to shift
xpos: x coord of base point to shift from
ypos: y coord of base point to shift from
and the rest is self explanatory :)
See: https://tikz.dev/tikz-paths#sec-14.7

Now I get what you want. Let me see

@wayne to red path in the new image is scaled down. If you put scale=0.5 and remove the x- and y-shifts, it will represent your curve

Anyone knows how to line break code in the posts?

Thank you. But isn’t there a simpler way to do this?

This computes the slope/angle of the line to locate the text and arc starting point.  I rotated the text mostly to verify the angle.
Interstingly, I could not get \settowidth to work inside the tikzpicture.
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\tempdima}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\settowidth{\tempdima}{links}
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw [->] (-5,0) -- (6,0) node [right] {$x$};
     \draw [->] (0,-4) -- (0,5) node [above] {$y$};
     \node at (0,0) [below left] {$0$};
     \draw[scale=0.5, domain=-6.5:6.5, smooth, samples=300, variable=\x] plot ({\x}, {((((2/437*\x + 5/437)*\x - 90/437)*\x - 280/437)*\x + 800/437)*\x + 7});
     \filldraw[red] (-2,371/874) circle (1.5pt) node[text width=2cm,align=center, above] {};% {\textcolor{black}{lokaler Hochpunkt}};
     \filldraw[red] (-0.5,2072/874) circle (1.5pt) node[text width=2cm,align=center, above, yshift=3.5mm] {};
    \filldraw[red] (7/4,371/874) circle (1.5pt) node[text width=2cm,align=center, above] {};
    
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\radius}{0.5*\tempdima+0.333em}
    \def\x{-0.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{atan(0.5*(((5*2/437*\x + 4*5/437)*\x - 3*90/437)*\x - 2*280/437)*\x + 800/437)}% y scale=0.5
    
    \path (-0.5,2072/874) ++(90+\angle: \radius) node[rotate={\angle}] {links}
      ++(180+\angle: \radius) coordinate (A);
    \draw[->] (A) arc[radius={\radius}, start angle={-180+\angle}, end angle={20+\angle}];
    
    \node[above] at (current bounding box.north) {\radius};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

